# Apply a series of functions on Django querysets using decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Let me first show my models :

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    .
    .
    . Fields definition

class CustomerWaterLogs(models.Model):
    saved = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    count = models.IntegerField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name = "water_logs")
    container = models.ForeignKey(WaterContainer)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    added = models.DateTimeField(null = True)


class CustomerSleepLogs(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False)
    end = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False)
    minutes = models.IntegerField(blank = True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer , db_column = "erp_customer_id" , related_name = "sleep_logs")
    saved = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

The customer model encapsulates some functions that return data from `sleep_logs` and `water_logs` depending on various conditions.

Now, in all of these functions, after the queryset is obtained , there is a need to calculate aggregates(max , min , sum , average) on some field.

Let me show two functions and functions for aggregations:

```
 def aggregate_max(field , qs):
    return qs.aggregate(max = models.Max(field))

def aggregate_min(field , qs):
    return qs.aggregate(min = models.Min(field))

def aggregate_avg(field , qs):
    return qs.aggregate(avg = models.Avg(field))

class Customer(models.Model):

        #Fields defintion
        def weekly_water_aggregated(self):
            today_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
            baseQ = self.water_logs.annotate(
                date = RawSQL("Date(saved)",[])
            )
            baseQ = baseQ.filter(
                date__lte = today_date,
                date__gt = today_date - datetime.timedelta(days = 7)
            )
            baseQ = baseQ.values("date").annotate(total_quantity = models.Sum(models.F("quantity")*models.F("count")))
            baseQ = baseQ.values("date" , "total_quantity")

            # *********************************** FOCUS On this Part*******
            #here i apply the aggregations transformations
            return {
                **aggregate_avg(baseQ , "total_quantity"),
                **aggregate_min(baseQ , "total_quantity"),
                **aggregate_max(baseQ , "total_quantity")
            }

        def weekly_sleep_aggregated(self , week = None):
                today_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
                baseQ = self.sleep_logs.annotate(day = RawSQL("Date(start)" , [])).filter(
                    day__lte = today_date,
                    day__gt = today_date - datetime.timedelta(days = 7)
        )
                baseQ = baseQ.values("day").annotate(total_minutes = models.Sum("minutes")).values("day", "total_minutes")

        # *********************************** FOCUS On this Part*******
        #here i apply the transformations again
                return {
                    **aggregate_avg(baseQ , "total_minutes"),
                    **aggregate_min(baseQ , "total_minutes"),
                    **aggregate_max(baseQ , "total_minutes")
                }
```

These aggregations can be applied in different combinations and are needed in over 10 functions right now.

So, to implement DRY, I wrapped the functionality to calculate these aggregates on Querysets using decorators.

Here is the code for decorator and how it changes the implementation of the functions:

```
from functools import wraps , partial

def map_tranform_queryset(iterable , *fields):
    #Iterable is an iterable of functions that accept queryset as an argument perform some transformation on it
    #fields is just a list of fields which the transformation functions might require

    def decorator(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args , **kwargs):

            #Bind the fields to all the transformation functions, so that at the last we can just pass the queryset
            partials_list = map( lambda x : partial(x , *fields) , iterable)

            #Obtain the queryset from the decorated function
            value_returned = fn(*args , **kwargs)

            data = {} 
            #dictionary to store the results. Mostly because i am using aggregating transformation functions

            for partial_func in partials_list:
                data.update(**partial_func(value_returned))
            #Iterate over the partials and obtain results and update the dictionary
            return data
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

This decorator now allows me to simply implement the functions as :

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    #Fields defintion

    @map_transform_queryset([aggregate_avg , aggregate_min , aggregate_sum] , "total_quantity")
    def weekly_water_aggregated(self):
        today_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
        baseQ = self.water_logs.annotate(
            date = RawSQL("Date(saved)",[])
        )
        baseQ = baseQ.filter(
            date__lte = today_date,
            date__gt = today_date - datetime.timedelta(days = 7)
        )
        baseQ = baseQ.values("date").annotate(total_quantity = models.Sum(models.F("quantity")*models.F("count")))
        baseQ = baseQ.values("date" , "total_quantity")
        return baseQ

    @map_transform_queryset([aggregate_min , aggregate_sum] , "total_minutes")
    def weekly_sleep_aggregated(self , week = None):
            today_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
            baseQ = self.sleep_logs.annotate(day = RawSQL("Date(start)" , [])).filter(
                day__lte = today_date,
                day__gt = today_date - datetime.timedelta(days = 7)
            )
            baseQ = baseQ.values("day").annotate(total_minutes = models.Sum("minutes")).values("day", "total_minutes")
            return baseQ
```

I would love feedback on this and the improvements i can make to this. 
Also, I do not know if this is the best way to handle the situation, what are other alternatives that i can implement?

Thank you for your time :)